# How would I keep highlight changes in Excel in Macbook

Tags: excel-2010

I am using excel 15.37 on MacBook Pro and can not find how to track changes and highlight them in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Macbook pro with the same version. If you go to Tools--> Track Changes--> Highlight changes.